# tfs 2013 to tfs 2015 process template migration

Tags: tfs-2015

I have migrated tfs from 2013 to 2015 update 2.
When I tried to configure the new features, TFS tells me they where previously configured as shown here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade

Therefore, I have to configure every feature manually, using witadmin as shown here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/customize/add-features-manually

The thing, is I have never used or customized any template in 2013, so I don't want to **update** anything. There is not user stories, backlogitems, etc in 2013. I will start using them in 2015 from scratch.

Question: Can I overwrite the whole template for the existing projects? Or I have to import every xml manually for every project?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created a Team Project, you unfortunately can't just upload a new process template simply.  It is like changing your mind on the blueprints of a building after you have finished construction.

However, there are still a number of ways to achieve this, you can select a suitable one depending on your situation. Detailed ways please refer this blog: [Upgrading your Process Template in Team Foundation Server](https://nkdagility.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/)